# android: how to delete a row from a ListView with a delete button in the row

Tags: android, listview

I know there are lots of threads with more or less same topic but none of them covers my situation:

I am populating my ListView with a custom CursorAdapter by using my custom rows. I have two states for the ListView: The first state consists of only texts in the rows; the second state has a delete button in every row. The switch between two states is a button at the bottom of the view.

What I try to achieve is: In first state, when I click on the row, the screen should switch to another view. In second state, when I click on delete button the selected row should be deleted from database, the ListView should be repopulated, and nothing should happen if I press on any other part of the row other than delete button.

I know how to delete an item and repopulate the ListView afterwards and I know how to switch to another view when I click on the row in first state; but I could not combine the two. I am using following method to get the id and position of the row:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
     //Code goes in here either for deleting or switching into another view
}
```

I tried to use some if statements to get the condition for delete button clicked or for row clicked but it did not work.

The first question is obvious: How can I make it work?

The second question is: In second state when any part of the row is pressed other than delete button screen switches to the other view. How can I prevent this? I tried to set .setClickable, .setPressed, .setSelected attributes of the row to false but it did not help.

Thank you for your responses in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> In second state when any part of the row is pressed other than delete button screen switches to the other view. How can I prevent this?

Simply have a listener for the deleteButton

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View row = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_result_details_row, parent, false);

        // inflate other items here : 
        Button deleteButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.Details_Button01);
         deleteButton.setTag(position);

        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Integer index = (Integer) view.getTag();
                    items.remove(index.intValue());  
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        );
```

In the getView() method you tag the ListItem to postion

```
deleteButton.setTag(position);
```

Convert the `getTag()` Object to an Integer

In the `OnClickListener()` you then delete the item

```
 items.remove(index.intValue());
```

Comment: Reno, here what is the need of deleteButton.setTag(position);, I guess without setTag() and getTag() also we can do it using items.remove(position);     notifyDataSetChanged(); or I am missing something useful?

Comment: @Lalit I think that won't work if there are `ListView` items that don't form a part of the actual items. (For e.g headers). In this case there are two adapters, one is your own and the other is the maintained internally by the `ListView`

Comment: @Reno Ok thanks for info, but I tried using what I insisted and is working, then too would keep and eye in future about your idea, it looks a nice way.

Comment: Integer index = (Integer) view.getTag();              What is view ???? how view is used can one please explain me ??

Comment: what is item and its remove method?

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code is better for the second question:

```
Button ic_delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.ib_delete);

        ic_delete.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // delete row from database
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        });
```