# How to refresh listview AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have a json file and I want to check this json every minute because my json changes every minute.
I can parse json from an url in this way;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ReadJSON().execute("http://www.url.com/json1.json");
        }
    });
}

class ReadJSON2 extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return readURL(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
            JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("level");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray server = c.getJSONArray("server");
                for(int j=0; j<server.length(); j++){
                    JSONObject serverObject = server.getJSONObject(j);
                    String name = serverObject.getString("name");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```

How can I check this json every minute?

I did everything, but I didn't it.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh ListView dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354692/how-to-refresh-listview-dynamically)

Comment: I have tried it but didn't work.

Comment: You want to use pull to refresh or just you want to refresh the listview, may be on button click or something?   Tell more about "everything" you did  ?

Comment: I want to refresh the listview every minute. @wonderPub

Comment: You can do it simply by onPostExecute use a handler to call the  AsyncTask after every minute. Before that clear the list and  on adapter call "notifyDataSetChanged"

Comment: Can you help me about that? @wonderPub

Comment: Tell me exactly what you want to do and how you are thinking to do it.

Comment: I have a json file and I want to check this json every minute because my json changes every minute. @wonderPub

Answer (score 0):

Use `listview.invalidateViews();` or `adapter.notifyDataSetchanged();` method in `onPostExecute` method after parsing your json.
This method works if some of the contents have been changes/added/removed in the list that is attached to the adapter. 
So whenever you parse your data . make sure the `object of adapter and the List/JsonArray` remain same. Means dont initialize it every time on web service result. Just use it like this  -> `list.add(some data);` and `jsonArray.put(some data);`

Let me know if i misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

We can use TimerTask to solve this problem:

```
public void initializeTimerTask() {

    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() { 
        //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                     new ReadJSON().execute("http://www.url.com/json1.json");
                }
            });
        }
    };


public void startTimer() {
    //set a new Timer
    timer = new Timer();

    //initialize the TimerTask's job
    initializeTimerTask();

    //schedule the timer, after the first 0ms the TimerTask will run every 1m
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 60 * 1000); //
}
```

An on ur postExe, after parse JSON, u should check Adapter here, if it's was empty for first time, you set adapter by this json, and if it's already has data, please call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Hi @GiaLe, I thing something is wrong in your code. Thank you.

Comment: can you explain more ? What result you have ?