# remove item from ArrayList with Custom Adapter

Tags: android, arraylist, adapter

I created a ArrayList with an Custom Adapter to show a delete-Button next to each item.
How can I delete one item in the List by clicking it's corresponding delete-Button?

I read that I have to add the following Code in my getView() method:

```
btnDel.setTag(position);
```

Next I should convert the position into an int since setTag returns an Object. How do I manage this?

And then, I should create a onClickListener() Function in my getView() like this:

```
btnDel.setOnClick....{
arrayList.remove(index);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

How do I get the number of the current selected remove-Button or what should I put in the remove()?

I'm new to android, so please give code-examples or easy-to-understand hints :)

Thanks.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7831395/582571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create something similar to this (at least this is the way which I was going to create this functionallity) :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        holder.name.setText("Delete");

        holder.name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            arrayList.remove(position);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    return vi;
}
```

Something similar to this should work for you.
Hope it helps! : )

Comment: And how do I check wheather my ArrayList is empty or not. I want to enable a Text like "Please Insert Item", when the List is empty and delete the Text, if there is at least one Item in the List.

Comment: Show me an example how you are populating your arraylist and initialize your custom adapter.

Answer (score 3):

you should put code in getView method and make position final...

```
     btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                arrayList.remove(position);

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You write code from getview method inside of adapter class and just check it for this code.

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
anyListener.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            yourArrayList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
```

}