# Delete row in custom ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view, it has a textview and a image button(delete). When I click the image button the row gets deleted and the list view gets updated.

Everything is working fine, but the problem is when there are more that one row in the list view, after deleting one row, im not able to delete the other because the position value is not appropriate.

To put it clear, for eg: There are 3rows in the listview.

- I clicked on the first row to delete( position value is 0), it gets deleted and the listview is updated.

so now there are two rows,

- Again I clicked on 1st row and it failed to delete.(bcoz the position value is not getting updated with listview, actually now its position value should be 0, but instead its showing 1 and sometimes 2)

Here is my code,

**CustomListView.class**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    holder = null;
    DataFields rowItems = (DataFields) getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_field_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.dataFields = items.get(position);
        holder.mName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.hmFieldName);
        holder.mDeleteImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.hmFieldDeleteImage);
        holder.mDeleteImage.setTag(position);

        holder.mDeleteImage
                .setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View v) {
                        Log.d("POSITION****", String.valueOf(position));
                        final Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();

                        holder.dataFields = items.get(position);
                        value = holder.dataFields.getId();

                        int status = dbHandler
                                .deleteField(holder.dataFields);

                        if (status != 0) {
                            items.remove(index.intValue());
                            notifyDataSetChanged(); //ListView is getting updated but not the position values of rows
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                    "Failed to delete !",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mName.setText(rowItems.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thanks !

**Edited**

As you all said, I did the following changes but still the position value is not getting updated...

```
holder.dataFields = items.get(position);
DataFields obj = items.get(position);
value = holder.dataFields.getId();

int status = dbHandler.deleteField(holder.dataFields);
if (status != 0) {
    items.remove(index.intValue());
    HomeActivity.mAdapter.remove(obj); //I also tried items.remove(obj);
    HomeActivity.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed to delete !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you do the delete part you should notify your adapter using `notifyDataSetChanged()`

**Update**

I think this is happening because you're using the view's tag as your index, this way your indexes never change. you should use the index provided by the `getView` method labeled `final int position`

**Edit**

can you try the following code instead of the one you posted as EDIT

```
int status = dbHandler.deleteField(items.get(position));
if (status != 0) {
    items.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed to delete !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I did that, see the comment line in my code. After removing item i have updated the listview using notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: I didn't get what exactly you are trying to explain. Can you provide me the code line for it?

Comment: you're unsing `final Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();`
and Then using `items.remove(index.intValue());` why don't you use `position` instead of the tag?

Comment: Im not able to use that with postion, do you mean it should be like this "getPosition()" or getTag(position)?

Comment: ok let try one other thing.. try putting `holder.mDeleteImage.setOnClickListener` after `holder.mName.setText(rowItems.getName());`

Answer (score 0):

you have created `DataFields` class that holds records. So remove any object from that array list or hashmap (whatever you have used) and just write below code after deleting any object from list.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

here, adapter is your custom adapter.

**Edit**

```
public class Contants extends Application
{
    public int xyz;
}
```

if you like to use this `xyz` object, you just simply need to write,

```
((Contants) getApplicationContext()).xyz;
```

Comment: But I cant directly use adapter of my MainActivity's class in my CustomListView's class rite?? Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Using the position we can
Object obj = adapter.getItem(position);
adapter.remove(obj);
//Notify the adapter
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: But that adapter is my MainActivity's class. How can I notify the same adapter in my CustomListView class??

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831395/android-how-to-delete-a-row-from-a-listview-with-a-delete-button-in-the-row

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because you are deleting an item, but it's still in ViewHolder, so you should update your ViewHolder DataFields after deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the adapter after the delete:

```
list.remove(adapter.getSelectedIndex());
reloadList();


    /**
 * Fixes bug where the list doesn't update. Call instead of just calling 
 * notifyDataSetChanged. 
 */
private void reloadList(){
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
}
```