# Returning the position in list in Android with OnClickListener on Button

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have looked over the internet and must be missing something. My task seems simple and I have found a few other post like it but I have yet to be able to get mine to work. The following is my code (sorry I'm new to java and android so if I have done some things that are not best practice I apologize.) Anyhow my situation,

I have a listView that populates a few text fields from a Database, at the right side of these text boxes I have created a delete button and would like for that record (row) to be deleted when the corresponding delete button is pressed. I have successfully created an OnClickListener for my button but am unable to obtain the position in the list view that the button has been clicked.

```
---------------------------------------------------
TextView  TextView    | Delete Button
---------------------------------------------------
TextView  TextView    | Delete Button
---------------------------------------------------
```

Code:

```
public class CalcCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements Filterable{

    private Context mContext;
    private ListView mListView;
    private int mLayout;

    protected static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected ImageButton button;
        private int position;
      }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CalcCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) 
    {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mLayout = layout;

        //mListView = .getListView();

    }   

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView summary = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.calctvPrice);
        TextView savings = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.calctvSavings);
        summary.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("qcFinalPrice")));
        savings.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("qcSavings")));



    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calc_list_item, parent, false);

        holder.button = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.qcbtnDelete);
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(deleteButton);

        bindView(v, context, cursor);
        v.setTag(holder);
        return v;

    }

    private OnClickListener deleteButton = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){

            Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    public long qcItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

I have looked at many examples and a lot of the time they look to be for Array adapters, The other thing that I have found is some people will override the getView function and I was under the impression that you could perform said task without doing that. Also, I don't want the list item iteslef to be clickable, just the button... it seems like it should be such a simple question but I have been looking... I apologize if this is covered well somewhere and I have just missed it, I have spent the last 4 hours searching the web trying to find a fix!

Anyhow, Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thank You.

Comment: Potential solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7831485/50913

Comment: I don't think that I should override the getView method. Is there no other way to perform this task except for overriding getView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Malachi's link points you to the right direction. There's just one tiny little detail missing.
Cursor has a method getPosition() that returns the position of the cursor in the row set.
Store that value in your ViewHolder and you're all set:

```
holder.position = c.getPosition();
```

In your OnClickListener retrieve the ViewHolder and the position it contains:

```
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
int position = holder.position;
```

The position can be used to retrieve the underlying data:

```
Object myData = getItem(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

For only button to be clickable in your list, just set the property of the button `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in your ListView_row.xml.

Now, you would be able to separate click events for the Button and the Listview.

Also, calling getView() is the best practice for building listview when doing customizations in it. Check [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) video tutorial. I am damn sure you'll never forget that you'll learn from this tutorial.

This is how i did for deleting multiple items from the listview, the difference is that i am not deleting any item from the list, but the records related with it, from the database and i've used imageview, instead of button. Atleast you can get idea how to do it:

```
public class DeleteData extends Activity {

Cursor cursor;
ListView lv_delete_data;
static ArrayList<Integer> listOfItemsToDelete;
SQLiteDatabase database;
private Category[] categories;
ArrayList<Category> categoryList;
private ArrayAdapter<Category> listAdapter;
ImageView iv_delete;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_delete_data);

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    manage_reload_list();

    listOfItemsToDelete = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    iv_delete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDeleteDataDelete);
    iv_delete.setClickable(true);
    iv_delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (listOfItemsToDelete.isEmpty()) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No items selected.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else {
                showDialog(
                        "Warning",
                        "Are you sure you want to delete these categories ? This will erase all records attached with it.");
            }
        }
    });

    lv_delete_data = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDeleteData);
    lv_delete_data.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    lv_delete_data.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) arg1
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageViewSingleRowDeleteData);
            Category category = (Category) imageView.getTag();

            if (category.getChecked() == false) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.set_check);
                listOfItemsToDelete.add(category.getId());
                category.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.set_basecircle);
                listOfItemsToDelete.remove((Integer) category.getId());
                category.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void showDialog(final String title, String message) {

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new Builder(DeleteData.this);
    adb.setTitle(title);
    adb.setMessage(message);
    adb.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    String btn = "Ok";
    if (title.equals("Warning")) {
        btn = "Yes";
        adb.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    adb.setPositiveButton(btn, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            if (title.equals("Warning")) {

                for (int i : listOfItemsToDelete) {

                    // -------first delete from category table-----

                    database.delete("category_fields", "cat_id=?",
                            new String[] { i + "" });

                    // --------now fetch rec_id where cat_id =
                    // i-----------------

                    cursor = database.query("records_data",
                            new String[] { "rec_id" }, "cat_id=?",
                            new String[] { i + "" }, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor.getCount() == 0)
                        cursor.close();
                    else {
                        ArrayList<Integer> al_tmp_rec_id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        while (cursor.moveToNext())
                            al_tmp_rec_id.add(cursor.getInt(0));
                        cursor.close();

                        for (int i1 : al_tmp_rec_id) {
                            database.delete("records_fields_data",
                                    "rec_id=?", new String[] { i1 + "" });

                            database.delete("record_tag_relation",
                                    "rec_id=?", new String[] { i1 + "" });
                        }

                        // ---------delete from records_data-------

                        database.delete("records_data", "cat_id=?",
                                new String[] { i + "" });

                        cursor.close();
                    }
                }

                showDialog("Success",
                        "Categories, with their records, deleted successfully.");
            } else {
                database.close();
                listOfItemsToDelete.clear();
                manage_reload_list();
                lv_delete_data.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
        }
    });

    AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
    ad.show();
}

protected void manage_reload_list() {

    loadDatabase();

    categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();

    // ------first fetch all categories name list-------

    cursor = database.query("category", new String[] { "cat_id",
            "cat_description" }, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No categories found.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        cursor.close();
    } else {

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            categories = new Category[] { new Category(cursor.getInt(0),
                    cursor.getString(1)) };
            categoryList.addAll(Arrays.asList(categories));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    listAdapter = new CategoryArrayAdapter(this, categoryList);
}

static class Category {

    String cat_name = "";
    int cat_id = 0;
    Boolean checked = false;

    Category(int cat_id, String name) {
        this.cat_name = name;
        this.cat_id = cat_id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return cat_id;
    }

    public String getCatName() {
        return cat_name;
    }

    public Boolean getChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void toggleChecked() {
        checked = !checked;
    }
}

static class CategoryViewHolder {

    ImageView imageViewCheck;
    TextView textViewCategoryName;

    public CategoryViewHolder(ImageView iv_check, TextView tv_category_name) {
        imageViewCheck = iv_check;
        textViewCategoryName = tv_category_name;
    }

    public ImageView getImageViewCheck() {
        return imageViewCheck;
    }

    public TextView getTextViewCategoryName() {
        return textViewCategoryName;
    }
}

static class CategoryArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CategoryArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Category> categoryList) {

        super(context, R.layout.single_row_delete_data,
                R.id.textViewSingleRowDeleteData, categoryList);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Category category = (Category) this.getItem(position);

        final ImageView imageViewCheck;
        final TextView textViewCN;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_delete_data,
                    null);

            imageViewCheck = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageViewSingleRowDeleteData);
            textViewCN = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleRowDeleteData);

            convertView.setTag(new CategoryViewHolder(imageViewCheck,
                    textViewCN));
        }

        else {

            CategoryViewHolder viewHolder = (CategoryViewHolder) convertView
                    .getTag();
            imageViewCheck = viewHolder.getImageViewCheck();
            textViewCN = viewHolder.getTextViewCategoryName();
        }

        imageViewCheck.setFocusable(false);
        imageViewCheck.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        imageViewCheck.setClickable(true);
        imageViewCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
                Category category = (Category) iv.getTag();

                if (category.getChecked() == false) {
                    imageViewCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.set_check);
                    listOfItemsToDelete.add(category.getId());
                    category.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    imageViewCheck
                            .setImageResource(R.drawable.set_basecircle);
                    listOfItemsToDelete.remove((Integer) category.getId());
                    category.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
        imageViewCheck.setTag(category);

        if (category.getChecked() == true)
            imageViewCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.set_check);
        else
            imageViewCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.set_basecircle);

        textViewCN.setText(category.getCatName());

        return convertView;
    }
}

private void loadDatabase() {
    database = openOrCreateDatabase("WalletAppDatabase.db",
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
}
}
```