# Android AdapterList with delete button on each line

Tags: android, dynamic-list

I'm new to Android & Java development, so forgive me for the basic question here. I'm trying for weeks to find a way to create an Activity, that would use an AdapterList, to dynamically generate a list of items on the screen. Each item/line would have a delete button besides it. The items would be generated from a textView on the top of the page, with a "submit" button besides it.

Unfortunately I was not able to reverse engineer any already existing example I had found online to do it, so if anyone has an example that does that, I would really appreciate your help on sharing that.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android: how to delete a row from a ListView with a delete button in the row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831395/android-how-to-delete-a-row-from-a-listview-with-a-delete-button-in-the-row)

Answer (score 0):

You should use RecyclerView and custom CardView layout. The layout should contains the buttons (submit and delete) and a TextView.
There are many tutorials of how implementing a RecyclerView with custom layout but I think this is a great [entry point](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).